# loop loop dynamically sized python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a loop that goes through a dictionary and assigns the values to another dictionary, eliminating the unnecessary and grouping the variable dictionary by sections.
The main dictionary has coordinates, url and image.

```
diccionario = {
    'coordenadas': ['e8da9f84fe', 'R', 'R', 'RF', '1c3278cc7e0d', 'RF'], 
    'url': ['www.aaaa.org', '&', '&', '&F', 'wwww.bbbbb.org', '&F'],
    'imagen': [ 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH5QgEFicFh0tlLwAAAcNJREFUSMftlr9LHEEUxz9v9pa7K/Q2l1yjmEJtDGkC8SoNHgiCXQoLScSEQMDCBIz/gpA/IcTKv8C/wEIIWFgKFoKFjWcjIrnDO8nMsxlhkUu8X3uX4h4MO/vmMZ', '/h7XffG1FV+mGGPtkA/P+DRWRcRGZ6Ck6lUiEwB2wYYzI9A1trXwNPgOequtITsDEmAqZjrlURGUscrKolIIy5MsBGomARmQDGGyzNisibRMBeUKV/hHwLgiDTdbC1tgjkYq5nQDr2PuqcW206e800CWNMXlXf+287BkwCT/2zDvwGqkANeKeqZ49msElBzQNTwAQw9GA57UfOH2ATWO8YHARBCCwALx4JDYE88NIYk3HO1ToCZ7PZP9Vq', 'dQt4BXwGhv8SegV8B07CMLztWFyVSkX9AQNgDdhtELYDLANFIF2v111XVK2qJ148b4FD4BNw5OeLQBn4AVyq6l7XVH3/H1trP/hU3wD7vph8BSKgbIxZstbWugr2lWvEp/Te4vOPqnqUSMlU1XPgoMHSdivQtppEoVA4AC5iruMoin623BdVteUhIjngC/ALGGlnjxRtmHPuWkT2gFOf/tavToML/QCclN0B6/vQXpiVJtAAAAAASUVORK', '5CYII=', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeAgMAAABGXkYxAAAADFBMVEX/wCfu7u7////mzZGcfw44AAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAAB3RJTUUH5QgFAQAIgup5ZwAAAM9JREFUGNNFkD0KwkAQhb8QYiFusNQD2FspokKOsIWNIGhhIgELwYtYqCEhRY6QI+wlLAQLD2BhZSOCs1toNR+8+XlvOMfZc5rkFWluYJRo0iPgCZx3Al', 'xFMhYGmgwmoCrWqI40aTTqLZqmJrzM4E7EpYihTeQXy7kRMP4r6hr6GIK6hwA09nO3FFUkBwdh9iodeCu1lWLwyrB0U/52pAUi/FOys5sJio09UdPcLOxRTWv8sDbE+/CGV1mrLWf1Z/4f5xcwFm0g2eUJ5iNP+AKAl0BF7aOg3AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==']
    }
```

From that dictionary what I want to do is concatenate '''diccionario['imagen'] with the rest of the string in the list to be able to join an encoded image. Each image goes in a range that starts with the first hexadecimal value of '''diccionario['coordenadas']''' and ends with the next hexadecimal value and contains a url.
I have tried the following code, but I receive several errors and I know that it does not solve the problem for me because it does not stop the loop in the next hexadecimal value and put it in a new dictionary list

```
diccionariofinal = {
    'coordenadas': [], 
    'url': [],
    'imagen': [],
    }


for z in range(len(diccionario['coordenadas'])):
    if len(diccionario['coordenadas'][z]) > 2:
        diccionariofinal['coordenadas'].append[z] = diccionario['coordenadas'][z]
        diccionariofinal['url'].append[z]= diccionario['url'][z]
        diccionariofinal['imagen'].append[z]=diccionario['imagen'][z]
        pase = z
    if diccionario['coordenadas'][z] == "R":
        diccionariofinal['imagen'].append[pase]+=diccionario['imagen'][z]
    if diccionario['coordenadas'][z] == "RF":
        diccionariofinal['imagen'].append[pase]+=diccionario['imagen'][z]

print(diccionariofinal)
```

Although now the dictionary contains only two blocks of images, this is only for tests, the range has to be dynamic to be able to add more blocks and concatenate the strings of the images.

in the end the final dictionary should look like this:

```
diccionariofinal = {
    'coordenadas': ['e8da9f84fe','1c3278cc7e0d'], 
    'url': ['www.aaaa.org','wwww.bbbbb.org'],
    'imagen': ['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', 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeAgMAAABGXkYxAAAADFBMVEX/wCfu7u7////mzZGcfw44AAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAAB3RJTUUH5QgFAQAIgup5ZwAAAM9JREFUGNNFkD0KwkAQhb8QYiFusNQD2FspokKOsIWNIGhhIgELwYtYqCEhRY6QI+wlLAQLD2BhZSOCs1toNR+8+XlvOMfZc5rkFWluYJRo0iPgCZx3AlxFMhYGmgwmoCrWqI40aTTqLZqmJrzM4E7EpYihTeQXy7kRMP4r6hr6GIK6hwA09nO3FFUkBwdh9iodeCu1lWLwyrB0U/52pAUi/FOys5sJio09UdPcLOxRTWv8sDbE+/CGV1mrLWf1Z/4f5xcwFm0g2eUJ5iNP+AKAl0BF7aOg3AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='],
    }
```

from the hexadecimal number to "RF" inclusive, concatenate all the "image" values ​​in the same range
"&", "R", "RF" are list fills and "RF" marks the end of the image composition, these strings are not valid and must be eliminated
Can someone give me any help or ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Please post what is your expected output

Comment: Hello!! I have edited the post explaining how I want the final dictionary to be, thanks @Ram

Comment: Is there nothing that needs to happen with the `'&', '&', '&F'` values in the `url` list? I don't see them used to produce your output?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect `diccionariofinal['coordenadas'].append[z] = diccionario['coordenadas'][z]` to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` is a method, so you cannot use square bracket notation like `append[z]`. Instead you need to pass the value as argument `.append(value)`. On the other hand, when you need to append a string to a string, you cannot use `.append`. Instead use `[-1]`, which will give you the *last* entry. No need to maintain a `pase` for that purpose.

It is also Pythonic to use `zip` when you have to traverse multiple lists in "tandem":

```
for coord, url, img in zip(diccionario['coordenadas'],
                           diccionario['url'], 
                           diccionario['imagen']):
    if coord in ("R", "RF"):
        diccionariofinal['imagen'][-1] += img
    else:
        diccionariofinal['coordenadas'].append(coord)
        diccionariofinal['url'].append(url)
        diccionariofinal['imagen'].append(img)

print(diccionariofinal)
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot it works perfectly. And thanks for the clarification of how .append works. I did not know the ZIP () function, thanks